# How to deal with low-graphics mode on startup?

Tags: 14.04, xserver

Recently on every startup I get error `unable to detect graphics settings` (this is from memory, so the message is not exact).

I am then offered to run in low-graphics mode for one session (other options offered do not work). Since this mode is perfectly fine, I would like to set it to run always without those error messages. How to do that?

The error in logs that I am given access to at that point is: `x server is already running` and goes on about existing `.lock` file.

Update. It seems that removing lightdm solved the issue for me, getting me exactly what i wanted.

Comment: Does `sudo dkms autoinstall` any output?

Comment: No output at all from that.

Comment: If you solved your problem yourself, please [answer your own question](/help/self-answer) and accept it. Don't put the answer in your question!

Comment: If i could add an answer to it, i would. I cannot find appropriate button for it now - probably because it is marked as duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

I would not recomment you to ignore this error. Just uninstall your current graphics dirver and use xorg driver.
To uninstall your graphics dirver go to dash and type "Drivers" and something like "Additional Drivers" should appear.